# mysql joining tables for multiple times

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
table 1                             table 2
id   q_id   content                 id    w_id     q_id    c_id    ranking
----------------------          ------------------------------------------------
95   2046   1=E                     123   22404    2046    100     0
96   2046   2=G                     124   22404    2046    101     1
97   2046   3=N                     125   22404    2046    102     1
98   2046   4=B                     126   22404    2046    103     1
99   2046   5=V                     127   22404    2046    104     2
100  2046   A1                      128   22404    2046    105     2
101  2046   A2                      129   22505    2046    A1      0
102  2046   A3                      130   22505    2046    A2      2
103  2046   A4                      131   22505    2046    A3      1
104  2046   A5                      132   22505    2046    A4      2
105  2046   A6                      133   22505    2046    A5      3
106  2046   A7                      134   22505    2046    A6      3
-----------------------             135   22505    2046    A7      0
```

I want to execut to this format(sd didn't calculate here)

```
id     content     av     total     E     G     N     B     V     sd
----------------------------------------------------------------------
100      A1        1        2       2     0     0     0     0      0
101      A2       1.5       2       0     1     1     0     0      0
102      A3        1        2       1     1     0     0     0      0
103      A4        2        2       0     2     0     0     0      0
104      A5        3        2       0     0     2     0     0      0
105      A6        3        2       0     0     2     0     0      0
106      A7        3        1       0     0     1     0     0      0
```

The Code modified base on Mark's suggestion:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.c_id in (t1.id, t1.content)
WHERE t1.q_id = 2046 AND 
  t2.q_id = 2046 AND 
  t2.ranking >= 0 AND 
  t2.w_id IN (22404, 22505) 
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Result:

```
id    q_id    content    w_id    c_id    ranking
-------------------------------------------------------
100   2046    A1         22404    100      0
101   2046    A2         22404    101      1
102   2046    A3         22404    102      1
103   2046    A4         22404    103      1
104   2046    A5         22404    104      2
105   2046    A6         22404    105      2
106   2046    A7         22505    A1       1
```

The c_id of row 106 should be A7 instead of A1, and the ranking is also wrong. As I have 20rows (A1-A20). The rows of A7-A20 are wrong. All the c_id and ranking of A7-A20 became A1 and 1.

Comment: err.. is it due to the condition 'AND w_id in (22404)'? Try including 22505 as well, like this : 'AND w_id in (22404,22505)'

Comment: Also, the c_id values in the 22505 records don't match any table_1 id values, although they *do* appear to match some table_1 content values - should the two tables be linked on this, as well? Additionally, there are no table_2 records corresponding to id 107 - should that row be included in your result set?

Comment: @MarkBannister i am so sorry that i made some mistakes, 107 should not be appear , i deleted that row already and keep id 135 in table_2

Comment: Note that the values in the tables don't exactly match the values in the expected results - for example, both 104 and 105 have a ranking each of 2 and 3, yet the expected results show them as having 2 rankings each of 2.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution identified by Noel, it's also worth mentioning that the 22505 records appear to need to be joined on c_id matching table_1's content instead of id, you have an unnecessary join, and your existing query mixes implicit and explicit joins - instead, try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.content,
       AVG(t2.ranking+1) AS av, 
       COUNT(t2.w_id) AS total, 
       COUNT(IF(ranking=0,1,NULL)) AS E,
       COUNT(IF(ranking=1,1,NULL)) AS G, 
       COUNT(IF(ranking=2,1,NULL)) AS N, 
       COUNT(IF(ranking=3,1,NULL)) AS B,
       COUNT(IF(ranking=4,1,NULL)) AS V, 
       STDDEV(ranking) AS sd
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.c_id in (t1.id, t1.content)
WHERE t1.q_id = 2046 AND 
      t2.q_id = 2046 AND 
      t2.ranking >= 0 AND 
      t2.w_id IN (22404, 22505) 
GROUP BY t1.id
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6f9c/1).

Comment: thanks for you reply. however, the selected data is not correct

Comment: @user2210819: Following your updates to your data and query, I have updated my answer with the new values - try now.

Comment: It works when I try it on SQLFiddle, However, the selected data is not correct if I try it on local. Maybe the data in my database affected the result. I showed you the result on top. 
Please refer to it.

Comment: I wonder why the result of the query A1-A6 of 22505.
SELECT *
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.c_id in (t1.id, t1.content).............

Comment: @user2210819: It's unclear what you are now asking, or indeed, whether you are asking anything at all. All I can now point out is that your modified query includes a `group by t1.id`, without aggregating any of the values in the select; consequently, your result set will be arbitrarily omitting rows from table_2.

Comment: The problem now is your code work fine in SQLFiddle. However when I try it in workbench, the output is not correct. May be I have other unrelated data in the database and the query joined the unnecessary data and cause the wrong output

Comment: Maybe I should change it into this:
    
    JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.c_id = t1.id OR t2.c_id = t1.content

Comment: I would be most surprised if that made any difference; `t2.c_id in (t1.id, t1.content)` is logically the same as `t2.c_id = t1.id OR t2.c_id = t1.content`.

Comment: I dont know why also , but Its really given two different results. Anyway Thank you very much x10000000